# While trying to install a fan, I accidentally plugged fan's GND and 5V pins to RPi 3B+ pins 2 and 4 (both 5V)

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

Instead of plugging the fan in pins 4 and 6, I accidentally plugged it in pins 2 and 4. The Pi immediately shut down. There are no signs of life other than the red LED that is on all the time. Is the Pi dead for good?

EDIT: The Pi still powers the fan if I plug it in the correct pins (4,6).

Comment: I don't understand how that would have done any damage to the Pi.

Comment: Did you do this while the pi was on? It's not a good idea to do wiring with the pi powered

Comment: Unfortunately it was on, yes

Comment: 2,4 are connected to each other so this will do nothing. You obviously did something else.

Comment: That's all I did, actually. While researching, oddly enough, I've found a post regarding a RPi forum user who has the exact same fan/case and did the exact same mistake (2-4 while the Pi is on): https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=231960

Comment: so, have you *carefully* checked if 3v3 is OK - like in that link you posted?

Comment: Doing what was said to have been done would not have caused any damage.  It is pointless speculating about what was actually done.

Comment: Bought a multimeter today, yes 3v3 is dead. Which apparently means the voltage regulator is dead. Searching for "Raspberry Pi 3B+ died for no reason" yields similar results, I wonder if I got handed a defective chip. Not that it matters at this point since I bought it as "barely used". Thanks for the replies.